# Can't use Jquery html() in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Can't work with html() Jquery function in bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("button").click(function(){
                        $('#alert').html('Wrong login. Please try again !');
          });
        });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <div class="text-danger" id="alert"></div>
  <form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Wanna insert a text error after user submits button but it didn't work. Look like bootstrap override the text after user did. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button type is submit, the form will be submitted and so you will not see the effect of the click function. Changing the button type="submit" to type="button" should let you see what you want.

Comment: It works perfect, really happy now.Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you. Happy to help 